# Authentication by certificate for WebFlux?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

In the regular Servlet API for Spring Boot Web, there is the `.x509()` of the `HttpSecurity` configuration. But in WebFlux's `ServerHttpSecurity` I can't find anything similar to it.

What is the equivalent of`.x509().subjectPrincipalRegex(...)` in WebFlux

End goal is to get the certificate subject as the username sent to `ReactiveUserDetailsService`.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you added a comment instead of downvoting, so I know where I have mistaken myself or what I am missing in my question.
Just downvoting is quite unhelpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a X509 filter as there was in the previous versions of spring, so you'll have to implement your own version of it. Fortunately the handy `org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter` provides the pattern for the authentication flow but you'll have to extract the subject from the cert/request yourself.

The first thing you'll have to do is setup an the authentication converter to extract the subject from the cert.

```
public class X509AuthenticationConverter implements Function<ServerWebExchange, Mono<Authentication>> {

    @Override
    public Mono<Authentication> apply(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
        try {
           // extract credentials here
           Authentication authentication = ...
           return Mono.just(authentication);
        } catch (Exception e) {
           // log error here
           return Mono.empty();
        }
    }
}
```

Now on our config we create the filter and converter beans and set the converter into the filter.

```
@Bean
public X509AuthenticationConverter x509AuthenticationConverter() {
    return new X509AuthenticationConverter();
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationWebFilter x509AuthenticationWebFilter(ReactiveAuthenticationManager reactiveAuthenticationManager,
                                                          X509AuthenticationConverter x509AuthenticationConverter) {
    AuthenticationWebFilter authenticationWebFilter = new AuthenticationWebFilter(reactiveAuthenticationManager);
    authenticationWebFilter.setAuthenticationConverter(x509AuthenticationConverter);
    return authenticationWebFilter;
}
```

And finally configure security

```
@Bean
SecurityWebFilterChain springWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http, AuthenticationWebFilter x509AuthenticationWebFilter) {
    return http
            .addFilterAt(x509AuthenticationWebFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
            //...
            .build();
}
```

This will work just as well with other authentication mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to upgrade your spring security version to 5.2.0 onwards. There is similar x509 authentication support available. Look at the below link.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.x/reference/html/reactive-x509.html