# Unable to send custom body in Webfilter if Authorization header doesn't exist

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-web

I am trying to intercept all the requests in my Spring Boot Webflux application (Spring boot 2.0.0.M7) using Webfilter and check for the existence of "Authorization" header. If not present I want to stop the request processing and send out custom HttpStatus and also custom body. Custom HttpStatus is working but I am not able to write custom message to HTTP body. Below

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBuffer;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DefaultDataBufferFactory;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.util.context.Context;

public class RequestContextFilter implements WebFilter{

    Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestContextFilter.class);

    @Autowired
    private WebClient.Builder webclientBuilder;


    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        LOG.debug("Inside RequestContextFilter.."+ exchange);
        String authorizationHeader = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        if(authorizationHeader == null) {
            exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            ApiError apiError = new ApiError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            apiError.setMessage("Missing Authorization Header");
            apiError.setTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now());
   // The below code of writing to body is NOT WORKING
            exchange.getResponse().writeWith(Mono.just(new DefaultDataBufferFactory().wrap(SerializationUtils.serialize(apiError))));
            return Mono.empty();
        }
        return chain.filter(exchange);

    }


}
```

ApiError.java class is nothing but my custom object I want to include in the response.

```
public class ApiError  implements Serializable{

       private HttpStatus status;
       @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
       private LocalDateTime timestamp;
       private String message;
       private String debugMessage;
       private List<ApiSubError> subErrors;


       public ApiError() {
           timestamp = LocalDateTime.now();
       }

       public ApiError(HttpStatus status) {
           this();
           this.status = status;
       }

       public ApiError(HttpStatus status, Throwable ex) {
           this();
           this.status = status;
           this.message = "Unexpected error";
           this.debugMessage = ex.getLocalizedMessage();
       }

       public ApiError(HttpStatus status, String message, Throwable ex) {
           this();
           this.status = status;
           this.message = message;
           this.debugMessage = ex.getLocalizedMessage();
       }





}
```

I curl the endpoint and this Webfilter does work and it sends the right HttpStatus code 400 but doesn't have the ApiError.

Request (No Authorization header):

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/accounts"--verbose
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
content-length: 0
```

The status works and the filter is being invoked but no object response. I did try to write the bytes after converting to JSON using jackson the raw bytes to DataBufferFactory but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

+1 to what @bsamartins said.

Now about your particular solution: the `writeWith` method returns a `Publisher`. If nothing subscribes to it, then nothing happens. You should replace

```
exchange.getResponse().writeWith(Mono.just(new DefaultDataBufferFactory().wrap(SerializationUtils.serialize(apiError))));
return Mono.empty();
```

with

```
return exchange.getResponse()
               .writeWith(Mono.just(new DefaultDataBufferFactory().wrap(SerializationUtils.serialize(apiError))));
```

With that change, Spring WebFlux will subscribe to the returned `Publisher` and your code will write to the response.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: Acually its returning response body, but not as JSON but some strange string with ?? marks inside of it. Could you help me what might be causing it? My class implements Serializable and is serialized to byte array.

Comment: this probably deserves a separate question with more details.

Comment: Hi @Brian, sorry for being so intrusive but I just posted a question about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49384626/unable-to-send-json-response-from-webfilter

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Spring AuthenticationWebFilter instead of creating a new one.
Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48111084/authentication-by-certificate-for-webflux/48249491#48249491) on how to use it.

Set your own `authenticationConverter` to extract the credentials from the header and then you can implement your own `AuthenticationEntryPoint` and set it on the filter to send a custom response to the client.

You can take a look at the default implementation for the http basic authentication on how to achieve that.