# Does anyone have a simple example of implementing x509 mutual authentication in Spring Cloud Gateway/Spring WebFlux?

Tags: x509certificate, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway, mutual-authentication

I am trying to implement mutual authentication (authentication with x509 client certificates) in Spring Cloud Gateway, but throughout my research, I haven't been able to figure out where to start.

From what I can see, authentication is not handled through Spring Cloud Gateway itself but instead should be done through Spring WebFlux -- please correct me if this is an incorrect assumption. I have found examples of implementing certification authentication through Spring Security, but I have not found any with WebFlux.

Can anyone offer some tips or even some code examples to get me on the right track with this?

Comment: There is support for X509 in Spring-security 5.2.0RC1. I am Struggling to get the X509Certs from the SecurityContext. Please let me know if you find any examples to get the certs.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure it in `src/main/resources/application.yml`, e.g.

```yaml
server:
  # for testing or development without SSL certs (HTTP) use an "appropriate"
  # non-secure port, e.g. 8080
  # for HTTPS use an "appropriate" secure port, e.g. 8443
  port: 8443
  ssl:
    # for HTTP set enabled to false, for HTTPS (with required client certs) set to true
    enabled: true
    # this is the spring cloud gateway _server_ cert
    key-store: /etc/pki/tls/private/server.p12
    key-store-password: servercertpassword
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    # this is the "bundle" of CA intermediate/root upon which the client cert has to
    # match
    trust-store: /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/java/cacerts
    # this `client-auth` option is where you *require* mutual-TLS, it can alternatively
    # be made optional
    client-auth: need
    trust-store-password: truststorepassword
    trust-store-type: JCEKS
management:
  # management port without SSL to allow monitoring/etc. without client certs
  # e.g. /actuator/health
  server:
    port: 8080
    ssl:
      enabled: false
```

If you have a set of client certs, a server cert, and trust-store / CA bundle, this is an example of how to configure it in Spring Cloud Gateway.

An X509 `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken` will be available in your application for successful connections made via mutual TLS, containing the principal/details of the client cert.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct about gateway using webflux where there is no standard authentication mechanism such as spring mvc.  The suggested way of authenticating is here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/reactive-x509.html

I also found the code example here helpful in setting up the application.yml file.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/reactive/webflux/java/authentication/x509

This post may also be helpful:
[Authentication by certificate for WebFlux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48111084/authentication-by-certificate-for-webflux)

This post is not with webflux but is helpful in understanding how to set up certificates:
https://www.baeldung.com/x-509-authentication-in-spring-security